# GMOCK Error: Is MOCK_METHOD11 not allowed

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

When I am mocking a function that has 11 parameters it gives an error message:

> error: 'function_name' is not a type

I am using

```
MOCK_METHOD11(function_name,int(param1,param2,....,param11);
```

Is it that functions with 11 parameters cant be mocked?

Comment: I'd be more worried about your function taking 11 parameters...

Comment: Yup - after about 5, (unless API or similar), I get an uneasy feeling that maybe something is wrong and I should maybe be passing in an object instance where the parameters are directly accessible or can be reached indirectly via instance members in the passed object.

Comment: You're missing an ending parenthesis as well. ;)

Answer (score 2):

GMock supports up to 10 (including) parameters for mocked functions. So you can't use it for your function out of the box. What you can do in order to mock this method:

1. (Preferable) Refactor this method to reduce the number of parameters. So many parameters make method difficult to control and understand.
2. Introduce intermediate proxy interface that would have similar method accepting only 10 parameters. That's easy to achieve:

   ```
   class OriginalInterface
   {
   public:
       virtual void method(int param1, int param2) = 0;
   };

   class ProxyInterface : public OriginalInterface
   {
   public:
       virtual void method(int param1, int param2)
       {
           method1(param1);
           method2(param2);
       }
       virtual void method1(int param1) = 0;
       virtual void method2(int param2) = 0;
   };

   // Now you mock on ProxyInterface
   class MockInterface : public ProxyInterface
   {
   public:
       MOCK_METHOD1(method1, void(int));
       MOCK_METHOD1(method2, void(int));
   };
   ```

In my example I split method with 2 parameters into 2 methods. I think the idea is clear.

3 . (Not optimal) You can try to change the gmock sources to add METHOD11 typedefs..

Comment: Fun & games, `::StretchDIBits` has 13 parameters, so #2 sounds like my best bet.